# Set Timeout running 4 times each minute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

for some reason a function I would like to execute every minute is running 4 times every minute.  I would like the behavior to only fire a single time.  I am unsure of why it is firing multiple times.  the code is as follows:

```
  const checkToken = () => {
    console.log('im running')

    const token = localStorage.FBIdToken
    if (token && token !== 'Bearer undefined') {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token)
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        localStorage.removeItem('FBIdToken')
        window.location.reload()
      }
    }
    setTimeout(checkToken, 60 * 1000)
  }

  checkToken()
```

Comment: Show minimal example, how do you call `checkToken`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using setInterval instead?\

Comment: @DennisVash I am calling it under the checkToken function declaration in my app.js right before the return

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval()` to run once every minute rather than calling `setTimeout()` multiple times...?

Comment: @brso05 I am unsure of how to acheive the same thing using setInterval could you provide an example I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @RobTerrell i posted an answer...

Comment: you don't have anything else in `checkToken` and is it not getting called inside another method? the code you posted here should work as expected.

Comment: @AZ_ I'm only calling it as shown before the return in my app.js very confused why it's running 4 times

Comment: what's the value of `decodedToken.exp`? I guess you need to clear the timer before reload.

Comment: also in react you should not reload but re-render whenever required.

Answer (score 1):

you are using this script in `react`, so make sure that this function/method is not triggering with component re-rendering. if you are using stateful component then move this function to `componentDidMount` to stop the multiple calls to this method. and if you are using stateless component  then use hooks to avoid this issue

you can also use the clearInterval to avoid this issue

```
const timeInterVal = null;



const checkTokenFunc = () => {
     if (token && token !== 'Bearer undefined') {
      const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token)
      if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
        localStorage.removeItem('FBIdToken')
        window.location.reload()
      }
    }

}



const checkToken = () => {
    if(timeInterval!==null){
      clearTimeout(timeInterval);
    }
    timeInterval = setTimeout(() => {
         checkTokenFunc(); 
         checkToken();
    }, 60 * 1000)

}


checkToken();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`. `setInterval()` you can specify a period of time and it will keep running based on the time interval you set...Pass `setInterval()` a function to execute and a time interval in milliseconds. The below will execute every 5 seconds.

Example:

```js
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);
```